# Fuerte install on Ubuntu 12.04 does not complete

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) and am in the process of installing Fuerte. I'm on my 2nd attempt and cannot get past the 89% point.  The install hangs at:

```
Get:350 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libtheora-dev amd64 1.1.1+dfsg.1-3ubuntu2 [415 kB] 89% [350 libtheora-dev 0 B/415 kB 0%]
```

I have reinstalled Ubuntu and tried again to no avail. I've also tried to install through the Ubuntu Software center, with no success. I'm not going to waste the rest of my day reinstalling Ubuntu and attempting to install Fuerte, because that makes me officially insane.

Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37743/fuerte-install-on-ubuntu-12.04-does-not-complete/) by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on 2012-07-03**:
Thanks. The mirror change worked, eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This doesn't seem to be related to ROS. It looks like a library cannot be downloaded correctly. I would try using a different Ubuntu mirror.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-07-02**:
@Lorenz is correct, libtheora is not a package provided by the ROS servers, this would indicate a problem with the Ubuntu mirror that you are using.  There are instructions on how to update your Ubuntu mirror on Ask Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/q/37753